# why the K-means optimization problem is non-convex?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, k-means

K-means algorithm    uses  a  residual  sum   of   squares   (RSS) where
$RSS_{K} = \sum_{d \in s}|{d-c(s)}|^2$,
$RSS = \sum_{k= 1}^{K}{RSS_{K}}$ is the  convergence  criterion. RSS is the objective function of $K$-means and our goal is to minimize it.

and $m(s) = \frac{1}{|s|} \sum_{d \in s}{d}$
where $d$ is the datapoint belonging to cluster $s$.

---

I know  there are two kind  of functions $1.$ Convex $2.$ Non- Convex.
For Convex function there is one global minima. But for non-convex funtions there are local minimas along with global minima,hence K-means  easily fall in trap of those local minimas. But I am not getting how that $RSS$ is a non-convex function. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: See [How to see that K-means objective is non-convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463453/how-to-see-that-k-means-objective-is-non-convex)

Comment: I have seen it, and not clear with those answers, hence have posted this.